# JAXB | MOXy | EclipseLink - The java interface com.domain.Entity can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, marshalling, unmarshalling, moxy

so I have run into a problem where I am trying to convert a complex bean structure into XML format.

I have five classes in the same package (annotated).

Each class extends an abstract class and implements an interface:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = SubscriptionInvoiceItemChargesImpl.TABLE_NAME)
@DataCache(enabled = false)
public class SubscriptionInvoiceItemChargesImpl extends AbstractEntityImpl implements SubscriptionInvoiceItemCharges {
```

Here is the abstractEntityImpl class:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntityImpl extends AbstractPersistenceImpl implements Entity {
```

Here is the Entity Interface:

```
public interface Entity extends PureEntity, Persistence {

}
```

Now, all I want is to just have the methods defined in my 5 classes (depend on each other through composition) to be written into XML and DO NOT want any data from the parent classes/interfaces.

Contents of jaxb.properties:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Here is the bindings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="com.domain.ecomm.impl">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SubscriptionContactImpl" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SubscriptionInvoiceItemChargesImpl" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SubscriptionInvoiceItemImpl" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SubscriptionAccountImpl" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="SubscriptionImpl" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>

</xml-bindings>
```

Here is teh marshalling code:

```
InputStream is = ZuoraServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/domain/ecomm/impl/subscription-bindings.xml");    
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, is);
    JAXBContext jc;
    try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {SubscriptionContactImpl.class}, properties);
         Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(subscriptionContact, System.out);    
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Running the code gives me teh following error:

```
Exception Description: The java interface com.domain.Entity can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple inheritence is not supported]
```

maven dependency used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The 'Entity' interface is in a different package than the other classes.
would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Since I could not get this thing resolved in the limited time I had, I ended up using Castor. Worked out for our use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the eclipselink parser, As a workarround used the **jaxb.properties** with content

> javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

the jaxb.properties must in the classpath in the same package as the class you are serializing

an other workarround is to use the version **2.6.0** of the eclipselink jaxb implementation